# GNOME Shell Extensions Disappear

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

[image: Gnome Tool Print]

"Extensions" should appear in the tool, but this function is simply not there. I would like to add the Dash to Dock but https://extensions.gnome.org/ does not find the shell installing even though the chrome and Firefox extensions are installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot it seems you have logged in to a **Unity session**, *not* a GNOME session. GNOME extension like 'Dash to Dock' is *not* supposed to work in Unity.

There should be a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the "sign in" button at the GDM login screen. Click on it and select GNOME instead of Unity (provided you actually have GNOME installed).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install extensions from extensions.gnome.org as they are also available in `Ubuntu Software` app.

Run `Ubuntu Software`, click add-ons, click extensions tab. Here you are able to install extensions.